# RESTAssured recieve one of two possible status codes

Tags: java, spring, rest, rest-assured

I have test(!) code of RESTAssured, that checks that REST endpoint returns me 0 as status code;

```
     given()
        .contentType(CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON)
    .when()
        .get(getRestOperationPath())
    .then()
        .statusCode(STATUS_CODE_OK);
```

But now it is possible that it also can supply code 404, that is considered valid output. I need my test to check that status code is one of the two, but I cannot wrap my head on how to do actually do it. Can you point me as to how I can do it, or if it is impossible?

upd:

.get(getRestOperationPath()) returns Response -> you can get status code and compare it. closed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also do this using the Hamcrest matchers, without extracting the response into a separate variable.

You can use a combination of `anyOf()` and `is()`

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anyOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

...

given()
    .contentType(CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON)
.when()
    .get(getRestOperationPath())
.then()
    .statusCode(anyOf(is(STATUS_CODE_OK),is(STATUS_CODE_NOT_FOUND)));
```

Comment: had to close the question to get right answer :D but I can't use hamcrest, so will he to leave with my version

Comment: Both are equally valid options. Just depending on the situation. No need to include Hamcrest specifically for this, but if you're including it anyway...

Comment: @heisa, imagine having expected status codes as an int array - `int[] expectedStatusCodes = {200, 201, 202};` Could you please suggest how to check whether the response status code has one of the values from `expectedStatusCodes` ?

Answer (score 1):

`.get(getRestOperationPath())` returns `Response`.
You can `.getStatusCode()` and compare it. Closed.

Answer just to close question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check for more than one error code within the body, you can alternatively do

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.anyOf;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

response
   .jsonPath()
   .getString("errorCode")
   .equals(
      anyOf(is("E_001"),
            is("E_002"),
            is("E_003")));
```

Comment: there is already better answer above, also using "anyOf" method.